# Bootstrap class breaks Capybara specs on Circle

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, capybara, geometry

I have in React a stateless component, which returns this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <button
      className="btn btn-default"
      onClick={handleClick}
      type="submit"
    >
      {selectedAll ? "Deselect All" : "Select All"}
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

For unknown reasons, adding `btn btn-default` breaks a few Capybara specs on Circle CI. Capybara throws just some ordinary non-random errors like *selector not found*, nothing unclear. Locally everything is green. I use `selenium-webdriver` and `SitePrism`, if that matters.

I checked these cases:

`className="btn btn-default"` - fail
`className="mysterious-error"` - pass (empty class)
`className="mysterious-error btn btn-default"` - fail
`className="btn"` - fail
Added `id` to the wrapping `<div>` - fail
Used `<a className="btn" ... >` - fail

I think the next step would be to break down the Bootstrap `btn` class, but this seems tedious as it's tightly knit with the rest of BS, so maybe you have some better ideas?

**FOLLOW-UP:**

Down the investigation, I determined that what's causing Circle to fail is a margin between two `div`s, which are totally unrelated to the failing specs. Also, it doesn't matter which css property I use to increase the margin: `display` and `margin` both increase it and cause failure.

@twalpole, always the same six specs fail, as mentioned before they sit in a totally different area of the website, and the errors are rather standard. Let me show you one:

```
describe "Remove Filter button" do
  context "when it is clicked" do
    before do
      filters.select_category(1, "Organisation")
      filters.select_matcher(1, "contains")
      filters.select_value(1, "Looney Toons")
    end

    it "removes correct filter line" do
      filters.add_filter
      expect(filters).to have_selector("div.filter-line-1")
98    expect(filters).to have_selector("div.filter-line-2")
      filters.remove_filter_line(2)
      expect(filters).to have_selector("div.filter-line-1")
      expect(filters).to_not have_selector("div.filter-line-2")
    end
  end
end
```

Fails with:

```
2) Use filters Remove Filter button when it is clicked removes correct filter line
     Failure/Error: expect(filters).to have_selector("div.filter-line-2")
       expected to find css "div.filter-line-2" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/filters_spec.rb:98:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Show the test step that's failing and the exact error message you're getting

Comment: @TomWalpole, please see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional margin was shifting elements to top so that fixed navbar partially covered action button. Clicking this button results in setting proper selectors on page. Shame Capybara silently failed on clicking the button, it even returned `"ok"`. This fixed the bug:

`page.execute_script "window.scrollTo(0,0)"`

Comment: Technically that would be a selenium-webdriver issue since it's supposed to return an error when it can't click on the element it's asked to.  If you have a repeatable test case you might want to file an issue on the selenium project on github

Answer (score 1):

By default Capybara only finds elements that are visible in the page.  From your description it sounds like maybe the style applied to the buttons is causing the `div.filter-line-2` element to be outside the bounds of its containing element and therefore not visible, or overlapped by another element.  You can confirm that by telling have_selector to ignore visibility

expect(filters).to have_selector("div.filter-line-2", visible: :all)

If the test then works (confirming the issue is that the element just isn't visible) then depending on why the element is becoming invisible you can try things like increasing the screen resolution setting for Circle CI and/or the window size.

Comment: Ignoring visibility has no effect, however, increasing window resolution fixes 5 out of 6 failing specs. The only one left tells me there are more elements than should be, which is quite the opposite situation.